# How to create a link to open a new sharepoint document from template with specific name

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

From our website (a support ticket application) we want to provide a link to a editable shared document for each ticket. It should be named <ticket-no>.docx

We would like to store this document on a sharepoint site at Office 365

On the website we can use the [Office URI Schemes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn906146.aspx) for an url like (`ofe` stands for Open For Edit):

```
ms-word:ofe|u|https://example.sharepoint.com/sites/testsite/<ticket-no>.docx
```

This works fine for opening an existing document but I have trouble opening a new document for a new ticket.
I can use (`nft` stands for New from Template):

```
ms-word:nft|u|https://example.sharepoint.com/sites/testsite/Template.docx|s|https://example.sharepoint.com/sites/testsite
```

This will create a new document from the template but I have no way to specify a new document name. The `|s|` part only allows me to specify a folder, not a filename.

Is there a way to open a new document, specify the name and base it on a template document?